# 1 degree stepper motor

Tags: stepper-motor

I would like to ask for some help regarding a stepper motor I would like to use. I need 1 deg step and as I have seen there is no such stepper. Could you advise me as an amateur the way i could bring this down from 1.8 or bring t up from 0.9 . 
What is easier and less complex?

Thank you,

John

Comment: IMO the best advice it to reconsider your 1 degree requirement. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 4):

One way to increase the resolution so that you can make steps close to an exact one degree is to use a *[microstepping driver](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=slva416)*.

[image]

That kind of driver works by PWM-modulating the current to the motor coils in a ratio that allows the rotor to stabilize in a position between the poles. You can't really increase the resolution by a huge factor, despite the driver stepping in (say) 128 or 256 microsteps but it might be good enough for you.

If you had 8 microsteps on a 1.8 angular degree motor, then each step would represent 0.225 degrees, and every 40 microsteps (9°) you'd be back to an exact full step.

You can make your own, or there are commercial suppliers such as Gecko.

Answer (score 3):

One way to change the step size is with a gear box. If you had a 1.8 degree stepper motor and used a gear box with a input to output ratio of 1.8::1.0 you would achieve what you want. There are two price you pay for this. First off a gear box can introduce backlash which shows up in motion as a latency at change of direction. The second price is that the stepper motor has to run at a faster rpm that the output will achieve.

An advantage of the gear box is that it will give you a mechanical torque increase at the load over the direct drive approach comparing both cases with the same motor characteristics.

Comment: He wants advice "as an amateur way" on how to do this. A custom gearbox does not really seem "easier and less complex".

Comment: Building your own wouldn't be all that difficult, for low torque applications.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your response and analytic information.

What I have found for anyone that will need something like I did, look at this :

http://www.omc-stepperonline.com/gear-ratio-91-spur-gearbox-high-torque-nema-34-stepper-motor-34hs384004dsg9-p-195.html

J.

Comment: To respond to other's posts, please post as comments (once you have sufficient reputation for this), or as edits to your question - This space is reserved for actual answers to the questions.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh: This *is* an answer to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. My point relates to "*Thank you for your response and analytic information.*"